# Swift filter dictionary error: Cannot assign a value of type '[(_, _)]' to a value of type '[_ : _]'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to filter a dictionary in swift:

```
var data: [String: String] = [:]
data = data.filter { $0.1 == "Test" }
```

the filter code above compiles under Swift 2 but yields the following error:

> Cannot assign a value of type '[(String, String)]' to a value of type '[String : String]'

is this a bug in the Swift compiler or is this not the right way to filter dictionaries in Swift?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**This has been fixed in Swift 4**

```
let data = ["a": 0, "b": 42]
let filtered = data.filter { $0.value > 10 }
print(filtered) // ["b": 42]
```

In Swift 4, a filtered dictionary returns a dictionary.

---

**Original answer for Swift 2 and 3**

The problem is that `data` is a dictionary but the result of `filter` is an array, so the error message says that you can't assign the result of the latter to the former.

You could just create a new variable/constant for your resulting array:

```
let data: [String: String] = [:]
let filtered = data.filter { $0.1 == "Test" }
```

Here `filtered` is an array of tuples: `[(String, String)]`.

Once filtered, you can recreate a new dictionary if this is what you need:

```
var newData = [String:String]()
for result in filtered {
    newData[result.0] = result.1
}
```

If you decide not to use `filter` you could mutate your original dictionary or a copy of it:

```
var data = ["a":"Test", "b":"nope"]
for (key, value) in data {
    if value != "Test" {
        data.removeValueForKey(key)
    }
}
print(data) // ["a": "Test"]
```

*Note: in Swift 3, `removeValueForKey` has been renamed `removeValue(forKey:)`, so in this example it becomes `data.removeValue(forKey: key)`.*

Comment: alright thank you :) that is just stupid from apple in my opinion. When i filter a dictionary i expect a dictionary in return...

I changed my code to be an array and use a combined struct to include both key and value (so that i'm not forced to use string keys) and than i use the filter function again, as this is the most concise approach.

Comment: Anyone know why Dictionary.filter doesn't return a dictionary? I'm curious.

Comment: @warly see Eendje's answer below. It's a different answer

Comment: Actually, tuple destructuring in closures made it back in the final release of Swift 4, so your note in the Swift 4 section is no longer true.

Comment: @Moritz It was in  one of the Swift 4 betas, but they rolled it back and deferred it, to be revisited later. https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170619/037616.html

Comment: @mbeaty Thank you. I've updated my answer and removed this part.

Answer (score 16):

```
data.forEach { if $1 != "Test" { data[$0] = nil } }
```

Just another approach (a bit simplified) to filter out objects in your dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

Per Apple docs, filter:

> Returns an array containing, in order, the elements of the sequence that satisfy the given predicate.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641239-filter

I found myself needing to do what the OP was asking about and ended up writing the following extensions (Swift 3):

```
extension Dictionary
{
  func filteredDictionary(_ isIncluded: (Key, Value) -> Bool)  -> Dictionary<Key, Value>
  {
    return self.filter(isIncluded).toDictionary(byTransforming: { $0 })
  }
}

extension Array
{
  func toDictionary<H:Hashable, T>(byTransforming transformer: (Element) -> (H, T)) -> Dictionary<H, T>
  {
    var result = Dictionary<H,T>()
    self.forEach({ element in
      let (key,value) = transformer(element)
      result[key] = value
    })
    return result
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let data = ["a":"yes", "b":"nope", "c":"oui", "d":"nyet"]
let filtered = data.filteredDictionary({ $0.1 >= "o" })

// filtered will be a dictionary containing ["a": "yes", "c": "oui"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this method to be useful after filtering or applying some other transform that results in an array of dictionary elements:

```
extension Array {
    func dictionary<K: Hashable, V>() -> [K: V] where Element == Dictionary<K, V>.Element {
        var dictionary = [K: V]()
        for element in self {
            dictionary[element.key] = element.value
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

To use it, just say something like:

```
dictionary = dictionary.filter{ $0.key == "test" }.dictionary()
```

The advantage of this method is that no argument of any kind needs to be passed to the `dictionary()` method. Generic type arguments tell the compiler everything it needs to know.

Comment: I can't compile with this show this errors :  
`Showing All Issues
/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Work4/BitBucketRepo/XXXX-XXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/Sources/Utils/Extensions/NSArray+Utils.swift:12:63: Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic`

`/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Work4/BitBucketRepo/XXX-XXX-XXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/Sources/Utils/Extensions/NSArray+Utils.swift:15:24: Value of type 'Element' has no member 'key'`

Comment: @ReinierMelian: I don't know what problem you're having. Paste the contents of [this code](https://pastebin.com/FA9vvv15) into an Xcode Playground and you'll see that it works perfectly. Make sure you are using the latest version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange ascending order according to dictionary value using filter

```
let arrOfDict = [{"ABC":24},{"XYZ":21},{"AAA":23}]

let orderedDict = arrOfDict.filter{$0.value < $1.value}
```

you will get below output:

```
[
  { "XYZ": 21 }, 
  { "AAA": 23 }, 
  { "ABC": 24 }
]
```