# Swift Dictionary Filter

Tags: dictionary, filter, swift2, tuples

So it looks like the filter function on a Swift (2.x) dictionary returns a tuple array. My question is there an elegant solution to turning it back into a dictionary? Thanks in advance.

```
let dictionary: [String: String] = [
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
]

let newTupleArray: [(String, String)] = dictionary.filter { (tuple: (key: String, value: String)) -> Bool in
    return tuple.key != "key2"
}

let newDictionary: [String: String] = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: newTupleArray) // Error: cannot convert value of type '[(String, String)]' to expected argument type '[(_, _)]'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: filter dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604897/swift-filter-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a more functional approach:

```
let result = dictionary.filter {
        $0.0 != "key2"
    }
    .reduce([String: String]()) { (var aggregate, elem) in
        aggregate[elem.0] = elem.1
        return aggregate
    }
```

`reduce` here is used to construct a new dictionary from the filtered tuples.

---

**Edit:** since var parameters has been deprecated in Swift 2.2, you need to create a local mutable copy of `aggregate`:

```
let result = dictionary.filter {
        $0.0 != "key2"
    }
    .reduce([String: String]()) { aggregate, elem in
        var newAggregate = aggregate
        newAggregate[elem.0] = elem.1
        return newAggregate
    }
```

Comment: I'm puzzled with swift 2.2 deprecating var parameters: can you still use `reduce` to construct the dictionary ?

Comment: @lazi74 Thanks for the deprecation note. Swift keeps changing so quickly and dramatically. See my edited answer for Swift 2.2-compliant code

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Dictionary so that it takes a sequence of tuples as initial values:

```
extension Dictionary {
  public init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == (Key, Value)>(_ seq: S) {
      self.init()
      for (k, v) in seq { self[k] = v }
  }
}
```

and then do

```
let newDictionary = Dictionary(newTupleArray)
```