# How to filter dictionary keys by regex in swift

Tags: regex, swift, swift3

Let's say I have the following Swift dictionary:

```
var studioAlbums = ["Led Zeppelin":1969, "Led Zeppelin II": 1969, "Led  Zeppelin III": 1970, "Led Zeppelin IV": 1971, "Houses of the Holy":1973, "Physical Graffiti": 1975, "Presence":1976, "In Through the Out Door":1979, "Coda":1982]
```

And I want a new dictionary which only contains "Led Zeppelin..." 
(i.e. Led Zeppelin,  Led Zeppelin II, ..., Led Zeppelin IV).

I've created extension methods for Dictionary and Array as per 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435190/7384373

then I could use string 'range of' method to find 'Led Zeppelin' as the following:

```
let filtered = studioAlbums.filteredDictionary( { $0.0.range(of: "Led Zeppelin") != nil } )

// print(filtered) output: "["Led Zeppelin IV": 1971, "Led Zeppelin III": 1970, "Led Zeppelin": 1969, "Led Zeppelin II": 1969]\n"
```

My question is for more complicated filtering I would prefer to use Regular Expression(regex), but I can't figure out any simple solution with Regex in let's say max 5 lines of code. (excluding any extension methods).

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the dictionary, really. It's just a matter of applying regex to any old string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the extension you are looking for:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {
    func filterDictionaryUsingRegex(withRegex regex: String) -> Dictionary<Key, Value> {
        return self.filter({($0.key as! String).range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil}).toDictionary(byTransforming: {$0})
    }
}
```

The extension is restrained to Dictionaries of type `<String, Any>` to avoid any Key to String conversion errors.

Result:

```
let studioAlbums = ["Led Zeppelin":1969, "Led Zeppelin II": 1969, "Led  Zeppelin III": 1970, "Led Zeppelin IV": 1971, "Houses of the Holy":1973, "Physical Graffiti": 1975, "Presence":1976, "In Through the Out Door":1979, "Coda":1982]
let filtered = studioAlbums.filterDictionaryUsingRegex(withRegex: "Led")
// ["Led Zeppelin IV": 1971, "Led Zeppelin III": 1970, "Led Zeppelin ": 1969, "Led Zeppelin II": 1969]
```

Edit: This does require the Extension of [user7367341](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367341/user7367341): [Filtering Dictionary Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435190/4503593)

```
extension Array
{
  func toDictionary<H:Hashable, T>(byTransforming transformer: (Element) -> (H, T)) -> Dictionary<H, T>
  {
    var result = Dictionary<H,T>()
    self.forEach({ element in
      let (key,value) = transformer(element)
      result[key] = value
    })
    return result
  }
}
```