# Swift Warning - Cast from '[(key: String, value: Int)]' to unrelated type '[String : Int]' always fails

Tags: swift

Given the dictionary:

```
let dictionary = [ "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
```

I want to create a new version with one of the items removed based on its key.  So I'm trying to use...

```
let dictionaryWithTwoRemoved = dictionary.filter { $0.0 != "two" }
```

... which achieves what I want HOWEVER the two dictionaries have differing types...

```
`dictionary` is a `[String: Int]`
`dictionaryWithTwoRemoved` is a `[(key: String, value: Int)]`
```

Which is consequently making my life difficult.

If I try to cast like so...

```
let dictionaryWithThreeRemoved = dictionary.filter { $0.0 != "three" } as! [String: Int]
```

...I get the following WARNING...

> Cast from '[(key: String, value: Int)]' to unrelated type '[String :
>   Int]' always fails

and the code also crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at runtime.

Help!

Comment: `Dictionary` does not have a `filter` function (yet). You are using the `filter` from `Sequence` but `Dictionary` is a sequence of key-value pairs. After calling `filter`, it's not a dictionary any more, it's a list of key-value pairs.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604897/swift-filter-dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an extension method to help you remove the values here you go...

```
extension Dictionary {
    func removingValue(forKey key: Key) -> [Key: Value] {
        var mutableDictionary = self
        mutableDictionary.removeValue(forKey: key)
        return mutableDictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to do this.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

let dictionary = [ "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
let newDictionary = dictionary.reduce([:]) { result, element -> [String: Int] in
    guard element.key != "two" else {
        return result
    }

    var newResult = result
    newResult[element.key] = element.value
    return newResult
}
```