# UISearchBar collection view sorting

Tags: swift, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a fruit class named Fruit. It is made up of

In it I create a dictionary

```
....
var kind: String?
var color: UIColor?

init(object: [kind : Any]) {

name = object["id"] as? String
...
```

I am able to populate a collectionView with this, but I want to try to implement a UISearchBar.

I have added everything, but I cannot find any good up to date resources on how to filter my collectionView using this delegate method

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
  ...  
}
```

Can somebody please either point me to a Swift 3 example or inform me on how to filter the collectionView based on the "kind" (not color)

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605193/5227674)? It also updated for comming swift 4. In the original swift 2/3 Answer the actual filtering part would look like that in your searchBar function `let filtered = data.filter { $0.1 == searchText }`

Comment: I hadn't seen that one, thank you!