# How to filter an Dictionary with a key and a value that is a structure in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, filter, structure

How to filter a Dictionary with a value that is a structure in `Swift 5`?
I intend to filter from the pool (dictionary) the stocks that have the structure field `'stock'` equal `'STOCK01'` `(A1, A2 and A3)`.

```
var pool = [String: StockOption]()

pool[ "A1" ] = StockOption( code: "A1", strikePrice: "10.1", stock: "STOCK01" )
pool[ "A2" ] = StockOption( code: "A2", strikePrice: "11.5", stock: "STOCK01" )
pool[ "A3" ] = StockOption( code: "A3", strikePrice: "12.7", stock: "STOCK01" )

pool[ "B5" ] = StockOption( code: "B5", strikePrice: "23.3", stock: "STOCK02" )
pool[ "B6" ] = StockOption( code: "B6", strikePrice: "24.3", stock: "STOCK02" )


struct StockOption {

    var code                  : String?       // "A1", "B2", ..., "ZE43", ... (unique key) ,
    var strikePrice           : String?       // just a price stored in string

    var stock                 : String?       // "STOCK01", "STOCK02", ... "STOCK99" (Can repeat)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: filter dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604897/swift-filter-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
let res = pool.filter { $0.value.stock == "STOCK01" }
```

Comment: In the playground your suggestion worked as expected.

But, I'm my real code just worked when I typed the following:

"let res = pool.values.filter { $0.stock == "STOCK01" }"

Thanks a lot!