# How to create a sub-Dictionary from a Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am wondering what is the best way to initialize a 'child' Dictionary with specified key/value pairs from a 'parent' Dictionary. As an example,

**parent dictionary looks like:**

```
["name": "Joe", "age": 45, "occupation": scientist]
```

Now I want to quickly create a child dictionary that only uses the "name" and "age" kv pairs

**child dictionary should look like:**

```
["name": "Joe", "age": 45]
```

Is there a supported Swift dictionary function that can do this? Thanks

Comment: You can “filter” a dictionary, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605193/1187415

Comment: If your original dictionary is large, and the new keys are small by comparison, it might be quicker to construct a new dict like so: `let newkeys = ["name", "age"]; let newdict = newkeys.reduce(into: [String : Any]()) { $0[$1] = dict[$1] }`

Comment: Thanks @vacawama. Something like this was what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to [filter the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605193/1630618):

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["name": "Joe", "age": 45, "occupation": "scientist"]

let newkeys = ["name", "age"]

let newdict = dict.filter { newkeys.contains($0.key) }
```

If your original dictionary is large, and the new keys are small by comparison, it might be quicker to construct a new dict like so:

```
let newdict = newkeys.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = dict[$1] }
```